# cat_index_position defaults to 10001. Magento 2.1.9

Tags: category, reindex, magento-2.1.9, index, position

Magento 2.1.9 right now. We have a fec categories and set the position according to our liking. However this isnt reflected in the frontend for every product. Some work, some dont.

Screenshot of the configuration. Everything else is pretty standard.Display Setting for sorting is Position in both cases. 
[image]

Now, when looking at the frontend however, things are not the way they should be. Notice the small little numbers above the products, these are takin from the getcatIndexPosition() function: 
[image]

A quick look into the databse gives us something like this: Filtered for the first Product with Id 1850. This happens in more categories for either all, or just some products.
[image]

Already did all the obvious stuff, reindex everything, cache clear.

On thing to add might be that the Category ID 70 which apparentely gets used for this, even though it should be using 56 is the root categorie. But no product is specified in it at all. 
[image]

Reindexing runs fine without any errors. We are using the m2theme evolution, but it also persists in the default theme.

Is there anything i can do to fix this? Any help is appreciated.